# How to create a user input exit code for this program?

Tags: java

How would i create a user input exit code for this type of program?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Testprogram{

   public static void main(String[] args){

      System.out.println("Enter any test score between 0 and 100");
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      while(true){
         double myScore=Double.parseDouble(keyboard.next());

         for(double x=0; x<=100;){

            char grade;

            if (myScore>= 90){
               grade = 'A';
            }
            else if (myScore>=80){
               grade = 'B';
            }
            else if (myScore>=70){
               grade = 'C';
            }
            else if (myScore>=60){
               grade = 'D';
            } 
            else {
               grade = 'F';
            }
            System.out.println("Grade = " + grade);
            break;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Obligatory:  Why do you need to do that?  An exit code of 0 indicates success of a running application.

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you want. It's not clear now. Also fix the code formatting, there is a special button in edit mode.

Comment: Also, what is the point of the `for` loop? It doesn't actually do anything.

Answer (score 1):

To return exit code from a Java program you should use `System.exit(int)`.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it by changing this:

```
double myScore=Double.parseDouble(keyboard.next());
```

To this:

```
String code = keyboard.next();
if(code == "exit") //if user types 'exit' then exit the while loop
   break;
double myScore = Double.parseDouble(code);
```